# Costura.Fody not embedding .pdb

Tags: c#, pdb-files, fody-costura

I'm using Costura.Fody to embed my whole application into one .exe file. But for some reason, the .pdb is not getting embedded:

[image]

On the project's [README](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/#includedebugsymbols) it denotes that there is a parameter called `IncludeDebugSymbols` to be specified in the FodyWeavers.xml that is `true` by default. Despite this, I have tried explicitly setting it to `true`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Costura IncludeDebugSymbols='true' />
</Weavers>
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's acceptable for your case, tell Visual Studio to embed the PDB.  This is a relatively new option.  Go to Project > Properties > Build > Advanced > Debugging Information and set it to "Embedded"

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022, the embedded PDB option is now located at Project > Properties > Build > General > Debug Symbols

Comment: I don't think it's supported. The documentation linked states "Controls if .pdbs for reference assemblies are also embedded.". It mentions "reference assemblies" only, not the main/executable assembly symbols.